# Recursive search for .sty file slows down texing process

Tags: packages, paths

I am running Debian 10 and using `emacs 26.1` to create a PDF from an `org` file via `xelatex`.  Everything works fine, but recently, the `xelatex` takes much longer than it used to.  When I trace the process I see a lot of lines like the following:

```
access("/home/loris/texmf/tex/latex/longtable.sty", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/loris/texmf/tex/latex/mtheme-master/longtable.sty", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/loris/texmf/tex/latex/mtheme-master/demo/longtable.sty", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/loris/texmf/tex/latex/mtheme-master/docker/longtable.sty", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/loris/texmf/tex/latex/mtheme-master/source/longtable.sty", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/loris/texmf/tex/latex/mtheme-master/doc/longtable.sty", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The individual files do not indeed exist, but the paths, such as

```
/home/loris/texmf/tex/latex/mtheme-master
```

do.  Thus, it seems like a recursive search for, in this case, `longtable.sty`, is slowing down the whole process.  The file is actually available here:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
```

So it looks like the search order for packages is incorrect.  Can anyone tell me where this might be configured?  None of the `$TEXMF*` variables seem to be defined in my enviroment.

Comment: check your config file (one listed by `kpsewhich --all texmf.cnf` for the setting of TEXINPUTS(.xetex)  your /home/loris/texmf/tex tree should be guarded by `!!` so that it is only searched when you use `mktexlsr` not any every file access

Comment: In ```/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf``` I have ```TEXMFHOME = ~/texmf``` and this is indeed included in ```$TEXMF``` without ```!!``.  This is the Debian default.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: normally texmf home doesn't have !! because its small and lets you drop files there without having to update the hashed list, and the big search trees are elsewhere, but you seem to have a big search tree installed there so ....

Comment: Actually the tree isn't that big (11 directories in total according to ```tree```) and the slow down has occurred several months after the last change in ```~/texmf```.

Comment: without !! kpsewhich essentially works like the unix find command and unless there are a few thousand files it's not usually worth the bother of using `!!`  and hashing the file list. So it maybe something else, you could try it and see,, otherwise I can't really help as that was my only guess, sorry

Comment: Is the whole of $TEXMF always searched through?  Is there no form of caching?

Comment: Ah.  The problem seems to be that I am accessing the ```org```file via ```sshfs``` and VPN.  Usually at work, I just have the ```sshfs``` layer and that works OK.  The overhead due to the (coronally overloaded) VPN seems to be making the difference.  If I copy everything to my local machine, the PDF file gets created in a jiffy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, the problem in my case was caused by accessing the `org` file via both `sshfs` and VPN.  These extra layers seem to cause a dramatic slow down.